# Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

Tags: griddb

Trying to execute 'docker compose build' for the project https://github.com/griddbnet/iot_project/issues
And get this error. Tried in Ubuntu and Windows as well. Can anyone help?

```
44.87 Building wheels for collected packages: griddb-python
44.89   Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): started
45.39   Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
45.40   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
45.40
45.40   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
45.40   │ exit code: 1
45.40   ╰─> [8 lines of output]
45.40       running bdist_wheel
45.40       The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
45.40       running build
45.40       running build_ext
45.40       building '_griddb_python' extension
45.40       swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
45.40       swig -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
45.40       error: command 'swig' failed: No such file or directory
45.40       [end of output]
45.40
45.40   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
45.40   ERROR: Failed building wheel for griddb-python
45.40   Running setup.py clean for griddb-python
45.73 Failed to build griddb-python
45.73 ERROR: Could not build wheels for griddb-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
------
```

```
failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -o pipefail -c pip install numpy pandas griddb-python" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```